# Big tilde in math mode

Tags: symbols, mtpro

How do I get a really wide tilde?

I need to cover at least  `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

The `\widetilde` command does not work. Nor using `\stackrel` with `\sim`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's no such thing: the result would be appalling.

Comment: Couldn't resist implementing Paulo's attempt from http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/do-we-need-a-beauty-alert-tag `;)`. @Lilia, please don't take this personally in any way!

Comment: @Mico Seeing that you, egreg and David (i.e. everybody who participated in this question) disliked the aesthetics of the output, and seeing that our mod Stefan [actually suggested this method](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2608/4012), which almost makes it policy, I thought it'd be applicable here. I wouldn't have applied the tag without a wink though. Feel free to revert it -- it might be worthwhile bringing up the issue on meta again, if we really want to apply this or not. If we don't want to do it when people like David Carlisle and egreg agree, I don't know when we would want to.

Comment: @doncherry - I continue to believe that it's not exactly a good idea to create such wide-tilded constructs. Everyone who wants to weigh in and declare their abhorrence of the resulting output should certainly feel free to do so. However, flagging such postings explicitly, with some rather ominous-looking signage to boot, is not necessary. Worse, having such signage might even attract some weirdos to the site who will try and post odd questions just to see if they can "earn" a "What you are trying to do..." flag.

Comment: @doncherry -- Seeing that Joseph Wright has already taken down the "What you are trying to do ..." sign, let's delete our comments. You go first.

Comment: @Mico: I'm fine with the sign being taken down, but I'm not sure if we should perhaps preserve our comments as basis for discussion on meta?

Comment: @doncherry I did not comment on any aesthetic implied by the question, merely on the result of my proposed solution (which is depressingly flat in the middle) (there is some parallel discussion in the chat session).

Comment: @doncherry -- I'm fine with not removing this set of comments.

Comment: This seems to have inspired Khaled to add wider tildes to XITS Math (sometime in the future): https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math/issues/22

Comment: wouldn't it be better to present this as `(...)^{\sim}` ?

Answer (score 43):

You could load the `mtpro2` (Mathtime Pro 2) to generate superwide tildes. An MWE (minimum working example) that shows how to do this is given below. First, though, some comments about this package: In addition to letting you do lots of really cool and useful things, this package also allows you create a summation symbol that's a full two inches (5 centimeters) [!!] tall. The font's creator issues the following warning regarding the use of such a symbol:

> ... thereby assuring yourself (as well as the designer of the MathTime fonts) the lasting enmity of journal editors everywhere. [Direct quote from p. 14 of the package's user guide]

This warning applies not only to using super-tall summation symbols; it certainly applies to super-wide tilde and hat symbols as well. Put differently: Just because the `mtpro` package lets you create certain questionable things (such as super-tall summation symbols and super-wide tildes) doesn't mean that you *have* to do them.

Here, then, is an MWE that uses the `mtpro2` package to place a ridiculously wide tilde over both `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` (ooooh!).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\widetilde{\mathit{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}}$

$\widetilde{\mathit{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**: The full `mtpro2` package is not free. However, its so-called `lite` subset -- which is all that's required to produce the rather dubious effects shown above, *is* free. This package is not on the CTAN, but it may be downloaded from [this site](http://pctex.com/mtpro2.html).

**Second addendum** (March 2013): The `mtpro2` package can also be used to produce super-wide "hat" symbols, by using its `\widehat` command.

Comment: I stand corrected: there is such a thing. But the result *is* appalling, so I wasn't completely wrong.

Comment: @egreg - I fully agree with you that the effect is appalling. I suspect that the availability of these super-wide accents in the `mtpro2` package is merely a by-product of having some truly useful capabilities such as "real" tall curly braces (both vertical as well as horizontal -- the latter for overbrace and underbrace constructions, I suppose). I would certainly hope that any author who actually submitted a paper containing such appalling wide-accented constructs to a journal would indeed earn the immediate and lasting enmity of all editors.

Comment: Mico:I will download now the mtpro2 package that you suggest. Thank you indeed for your help.

Answer (score 28):

**REVISED SOLUTION** (with `\AC` from `wasysym`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine,wasysym}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{-.1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\AC}{.5150\wd0}}{.6\ht0}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\def\test#1{$%
  \reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

\test{abcdefghijklm}
\test{abcdefghijk}
\test{abcdefghi}
\test{abcdefg}
\test{abcde}
\test{abc}
\test{ab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION** (with `\sim`)

Given the year since this solution was posted, I have learned quite a bit, and so I REEDIT this answer to correct deficiencies like "wrong vertical axis", "does not scale with mathstyle", "extra dead-zone width", etc.  This new result uses the 10 MAR 2014 version of `scalerel`, so you may have to update.

At the end of the MWE, I show how I determined the `.2mu` and `.5467` parameters used in the new macro.  A user doesn't need to pay attention to it, but if one wanted to adapt this to a different top decoration, a similar procedure would come in handy.  In a nutshell, I kerned away the space on the sides of `\sim` and determined the kern trim mismatch of .2mu.  This was added into the macro, so that the tilde would not be offset left or right relative to the argument.  I also calculated the aspect ratio of the trimmed `\sim` as .5467.  In the macro, this is multiplied by `\wd0`, the argument width, to indicate how tall a *scaled* `\sim` would have to be to horizontally stretch over the width of the argument.  I then squash it down to vertically to the desired height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2014/03/10]
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{-.1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\sim}{.5467\wd0}}{.7\ht0}%
%    .2mu is the kern imbalance when clipping white space
%    .5467++++ is \ht/[kerned \wd] aspect ratio for \sim glyph
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\def\test#1{$%
  \reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

\test{abcdefghijklm}
\test{abcdefghijk}
\test{abcdefghi}
\test{abcdefg}
\test{abcde}
\test{abc}
\test{ab}

How .55 multiplier in scaleto was determined:
\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=.1pt
\setbox0=\hbox{$\mkern-.86mu\sim\mkern-1.06mu$}

kerned width: \the\wd0, height: \the\ht0, 

kerned sim glyph: \fbox{\box0}

Net kern imbalance: $-0.86\mu - (-1.06\mu) = 0.20\mu$

aspect ratio: height/width = 0.5467

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the most elegant solution out of the several above that I tried. Incidentally, I had vertical alignment problems (the tilde in tension with the text below it) until I edited as `#1\\ <CR> \rule{-1ex}{0ex}` before `\end{array}` as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol/101136#101136

Comment: @MarkWayne  Thanks so much.  Glad to help.  You are right on the vertical alignment.  With what I've learned this last year, I'll work on an improvement.

Comment: @MarkWayne Please see improved revision.

Answer (score 17):

It's sort of horrible, but it does stretch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\oversortoftilde#1{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}%
      \sortoftildefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
      $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}

\def\sortoftildefill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \widetilde{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\]
\[ \oversortoftilde{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, this to me would be the preferred form!  Old manuscripts that needed long tildes for abbreviations did it in this way.

Answer (score 7):

I tried some of these except the {mtpro2} since for submitting articles that might not be acceptable by publishers!

As I was not satisfied by the previous methods mentioned above, I tried to tailor another method, you can apply the following code, play with the scale factors and positions and choose which one you prefer. The last two I recommend but I myself prefer the last, which I am going to use myself:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}

\[\widetilde{ABCDEF}\]

\[\stackon[0pt]{ABCDEF}{\hstretch{7.0}{\sim}}\]

\[\stackon[-8pt]{ABCDEF}{\vstretch{1.5}{\hstretch{9.0}{\widetilde{\phantom{\;}}}}}\]

\[\stackon[-8pt]{ABCDEF}{\vstretch{1.5}{\hstretch{2.4}{\widetilde{\phantom{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;}}}}}\]

\end{document}
```

The result would be something like this:

[image]

Have fun

Ehsan Tavakoli

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: I needed a good looking `argmin` with wide tilde on top.

I settled on `$\stackrel{\resizebox{6mm}{1mm}{$\ \sim$}}{\argmin}$`.

Result:
[image]

Note: the 3rd argument of `\resizebox` is interpreted as text mode, so you need to put in the `$` signs explicitly. The extra space (`\` ) before the tilde (`\sim`) is a hack to make it look centered.

I think it looks worse edge-to-edge: [image]

`\stackrel{\resizebox{11mm}{1mm}{$\sim$}}{\argmin}`