# How to write geometric arcs notation without arcs package?

Tags: arc

I've tried some other packages: yhmath and mathdesign, and some codes:

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMX}{}{}%%%
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}%%%
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widearc}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{216}
```

and

```
\def\frown{\XeTeXmathaccent"0"1"23DC}
```

These solutions haven't work at all, some mess up my other symbols like parenthesis, brackets and so on.

Is there a simple way to place an arc or similar over two or three letters?

I made it to here, after some comments and trying to figure it out, I made the arc symbol like this.

```
\renewcommand{\overarc}[1]{\ooalign{\hfil\scalebox{0.9}{$#1$}\hfil\cr\hfil\raisebox{8pt}{\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{1}{$)$}}}\hfil\cr}}
```

It worked well for my proporses. but any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The `arcs` package has very serious bugs. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86036/use-overarc-to-represent-an-arc and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/frown-and-mathop-stackrel-overset

Comment: See Werner's answer to [a-better-notation-to-denote-arcs-for-an-american-high-school-textbook](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96680/a-better-notation-to-denote-arcs-for-an-american-high-school-textbook/96681#96681).

Comment: @hkviktor Did you look at the link I posted above? I think it solves your problem

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you mean?  It is based on my answer at [Typesetting arc over the letter upside down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152552/typesetting-arc-over-the-letter-upside-down/152675#152675)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath

\newcommand\reallywidefrown[1]{%
\stackon[0pt]{#1}{%
\stretchto{%
  \scaleto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{#1}]{\mkern-1.5mu\frown\mkern-2mu}%
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%
  }{\textheight}%
}{0.8ex}}%
}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

$\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghijklm}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghijk}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghi}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbcdefg}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbcde}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbc}$

$\reallywidefrown{zb}$

$\reallywidefrown{z} = 0$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you require a version that preserves the math style, a less efficient version is available:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\newcommand\reallywidefrown[1]{\ThisStyle{%
\sbox\tmpbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
\stackon[0pt]{\usebox{\tmpbox}}{%
\stretchto{%
  \scaleto{%
    \scalerel*[\wd\tmpbox]{\mkern-.8mu\frown\mkern-.8mu}%
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%
  }{\textheight}%
}{0.8ex}}%
}}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

$\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghijklm} \quad\scriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghijklm}
  \quad\scriptscriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghijklm}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghijk} \quad\scriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghijk}
  \quad\scriptscriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghijk}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghi} \quad\scriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghi}
  \quad\scriptscriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcdefghi}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbcdefg} \quad\scriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcdefg}
  \quad\scriptscriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcdefg}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbcde} \quad\scriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcde}
  \quad\scriptscriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbcde}$

$\reallywidefrown{zbc} \quad\scriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbc}
  \quad\scriptscriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zbc}$

$\reallywidefrown{zb} \quad\scriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zb}
  \quad\scriptscriptstyle\reallywidefrown{zb}$

$\reallywidefrown{z} = 0$

\end{document}
```

[image]