# How can I write text with curved arrows over and underneath

Tags: arrows, text-decorations

I want to make a notation for a cycle ABC. Currently I'm using regular arrows over and underneath like in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\cycle}[1]{
    \underleftarrow{\overrightarrow{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
Using the cycle $\cycle{ABC}$.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of my current code]

Is it possible to make the arrows slightly curved, like this crudely drawn example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution based on this: [Make \curvearrowright longer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461961/make-curvearrowright-longer). I adapted it to both an arrow above and below the word.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{cycle}
\newcommand{\cycle}[1]{\stepcounter{cycle}\tikzset{tikzmark prefix=\thecycle}\tikzmark{start}#1\tikzmark{stop}\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
% over arrow
\draw[->]([shift={(.5ex,2ex)}]pic cs:start) to[bend left=10] ([shift={(-.5ex,2ex)}]pic cs:stop);
% under arrow
\draw[->]([shift={(-.5ex,-.5ex)}]pic cs:stop) to[bend left=10] ([shift={(.5ex,-.5ex)}]pic cs:start)}}

\begin{document}
Using the cycle \cycle{ABC}
\end{document}
```

This gives output: [image]

Within a block of text, this looks as follows:
[image]