# A ugly \arc (\widearc, \wideparen) using [lite] mtpro2

Tags: macros, symbols, mtpro

I mention these two links for my question.

1. [A better notation to denote arcs for an American high school textbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96680/a-better-notation-to-denote-arcs-for-an-american-high-school-textbook)
2. [frown and mathop/stackrel/overset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/frown-and-mathop-stackrel-overset)

I'm trying to write an arc on two letters, but the result is very ugly. In fact the arc symbol is it's too up high, it's not centered with the two letters and it's shifted to the left. Do I need to use a *macro* or is there a command I don't know about in the `mtpro2` guide? I don't have to use other packages otherwise in my book I make the salad of packages that contrast each other.

Here there are the MWE and the screenshot.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\DeclareSymbolFont{yhlargesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{\mathord}{yhlargesymbols}{"F3}
\begin{document}
$\widearc{AB}, \arc{AB}, \wideparen{AB}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I have used the @egreg's answer without additional package.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193829/how-to-write-geometric-arcs-notation-without-arcs-package

Comment: I see it neither too high nor shifted.

Comment: @egreg I have taken in consideration your suggestions (this comment is also for Steven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `tikzmark` library of TikZ ? the arc is exactly in between, and we can control height of arcs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\tikzarc}[1]{%
\tikzmarknode{a}{#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw ([yshift=1pt]a.north west) to[bend left=20] ([yshift=1pt]a.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}% end of \tikzarc
\begin{document}
These are inline arcs with \verb|tikzmark| in TikZ: with $2$ points $\tikzarc{AB}$, with $3$ points $\tikzarc{CDE}$, with $4$ points $\tikzarc{FGHI}$, $\tikzarc{xyz}$, and $\tikzarc{AmB}$. 

The followings are arcs in display mode
$$\tikzarc{AB}$$ 
$$\tikzarc{CDE}$$
$$\tikzarc{FGHI}$$
$$\tikzarc{xyz}$$
$$\tikzarc{AmB}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.