# Is there an \xlongsim? (similar to \xlongequal{textext})

Tags: packages, mathdesign

One can use the extra arrows package to write e.g. `\xlongequal{\text{a long text...}}` then the result is that the equal sign is stretched so that the text above it fits on it. Is there a similar thing one can do with arbitrary mathematical signs? For instance

`\xlongsim` is desired at the moment where I want to extend `\sim`.

Comment: Don't. Please, not this one.

Comment: Hahaha @egreg, I'm sorry, are there any particular problems with this one?

Comment: See similar horrors here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode