# \widetilde{} alternative for formula over the tilde

Tags: math-mode, tilde

I'd like to put some formula over the tilde in math mode and adjust the tilde length to the length of that formula. It seems that `\widetilde{}` is almost what I need, however it puts the formula below the tilde. Is there a way to actually put the formula above?

An example of the formula to put above is:

```
\widetilde{(p_1',p_2') \in C}
```

Edit: I wasn't exactly clear with the expected effect. I'd like to have tilde in the middle of line (like `\sim` does), however with the formula above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took my answer at [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode/101138#101138) and made two changes:  1) I changed it from an overstack to an understack; and 2) I increased the vertical stacking gap to `\LMpt`, which is 1pt scaled to the local mathstyle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2014/03/10]
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\sim}{.5467\wd0}}{.7\ht0}%
%    .2mu is the kern imbalance when clipping white space
%    .5467++++ is \ht/[kerned \wd] aspect ratio for \sim glyph
  }{U}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\def\test#1{$%
  \reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
$x = \reallywidetilde{(p_1',p_2') \in C}$

$\scriptstyle x = \reallywidetilde{(p_1',p_2') \in C}$

$\scriptscriptstyle x = \reallywidetilde{(p_1',p_2') \in C}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, by some chance, you actually wanted the text over the tilde (rather than the tilde under the text), that is also easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2014/03/10]
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{\LMpt}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\sim}{.5467\wd0}}{.7\ht0}%
    }{$\SavedStyle#1$%
%    .2mu is the kern imbalance when clipping white space
%    .5467++++ is \ht/[kerned \wd] aspect ratio for \sim glyph
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\def\test#1{$%
  \reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
$xyz \reallywidetilde{(p_1',p_2') \in C} abc$

$xyz {\scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{(p_1',p_2') \in C}} abc$

$xyz {\scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{(p_1',p_2') \in C}} abc$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've utilized over a hundred instances of your `\reallywidetilde` code in my project for well over a year. While attempting to implement a `pdflatex` to `lualatex` conversion, I've located where the `\scaleto` command appears to error with a `! Missing number, treated as zero.`, likely due to a `font` implementation issue that I've not properly addressed (e.g. `Missing character: There is no ∶ (U+2236) in font mdugmr7t!`). As a neophyte to the conversion, any thoughts as to how or what I should look for to help address the `Missing number` issue would be appreciated.

Comment: @RosesBouquet I am not an expert in the topic of your question.  The only glyph intrinsically used by `\reallywidetilde` is `\sim`.  And yet, your error code refers to U+2236, which, the best I can tell, is the "ratio" colon: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2236.  So I really don't have a good understanding of what is happening.

Comment: Thank you Steven ... let me try to work this out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The package undertilde by Benjamin Bayart has it.

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/undertilde

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work exactly as I expected. Edited  question.