# Create a binary operator for "independent and identically distributed as"

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am trying to write the following mathematical expression in latex:

[image]

Can anybody help me out about how can I write this in latex?

Comment: maybe have a look at the second part of this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210626/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ; No, that answer isn't helping. \reallywidetilde command is not working for me.

Comment: -1: This question does not show any research effort, has a non-descript title and doesn't provide foundational code to support answers.

Answer (score 8):

This code:

```
\documentclass[border=15]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$z_1, \ldots, z_n \stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} N(0, \sigma^2)$
\end{document}
```

produces exactly what is in your figure.

Comment: Please post the suggestion in executable format as always....

Comment: @MadyYuvi, done!

Comment: `amsmath` isn't really necessary here (`\stackrel` is a kernel macro).

Answer (score 6):

Another solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand{\iid}{\mathbin{\ooalign{\hidewidth\raise1.2ex\hbox{\tiny i.i.d}\hidewidth\cr$\sim$\cr}}}
\begin{document}
$ z_1, \dots, z_n \iid N(0, \sigma^2) $
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

but I think I prefer it without the dots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand{\iid}{\mathbin{\ooalign{\hidewidth\raise1.2ex\hbox{\tiny iid}\hidewidth\cr$\sim$\cr}}}
\begin{document}
$ z_1, \dots, z_n \iid N(0, \sigma^2) $
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details of `ooalign` see [this highly rated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/15036).

Answer (score 5):

Plain TeX uses macro `\buildrel` for such purposes:

```
$ z_1, \dots, z_n \buildrel\rm iid \over\sim N(0, \sigma^2) $
\bye
```