# Transpose of a matrix with tilde:

Tags: stacking-symbols

What is the best way to write the transpose with a tilde on top? Some authors use this notation. I used `\overset{\thicksim}{ABC}` because `\tilde{ABC}` does not work either. The idea is that the tilde extends from A to C. How can I achieve this?

[image]

I want to get something like:

[image]

Comment: The command is `\widetilde{ABC}` but I warn you, this is not the most elegant of notations imho! :P

Comment: Lots of juicy info here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode

Comment: But that post is about a tilde that covers the entire alphabet; I think three letters looks ok.

Comment: @JPi yes I just thought the OP might be interested in that post, as it provides more information, but I didn't mark this question as a dupe because, as you say, the OP just wants three letters. Just three letters seems to be within what `\widetilde{}` as designed for and it does look okay, but I wouldn't use that notation myself. Not that the OP is under any obligation to listen to me on matters of taste (I mean you should see what I'm wearing right now) but I couldn't in all good conscience give the answer without a warning :P

Comment: `\widetilde{}` is quite angular and doesn't really look as nice as the OP's hand-drawn effort (which I still think is imperfect notation, but matters of style are up to authors and really off-topic here)

Comment: Please use something else for transpose. It is horrible to keep track of them in the articles when they are `X\tilde{YZ}W` etc. `^T` is just fine for my taste.

Comment: @Au101 I know... It's just for a course that I'm taking. We adopted this notation for the course and I'm writing my homework in latex. Anyway, thanks a lot. Didn't know that command.

Comment: (I wouldn't use this notation myself, either)