# How does one make a 'proper' (aesthetically pleasing) double widetilde?

Tags: stacking-symbols

I'm heaving problems with correctly vertically stacking two widetilde's (i.e. one on top of the other). I managed to reduce the space between them, but I don't know how to force them to be exactly vertically aligned.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%define doublewidetilde
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\doublewidetilde}[1]{{%
\mathpalette\double@widetilde{#1}%
}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\double@widetilde}[2]{%
\sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\widetilde{#2}$}%
\ht\z@=.85\ht\z@
\widetilde{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
E.g.: $\doublewidetilde{I}_N$ or $\doublewidetilde{abcde}_N$
\end{document}
```

Also, notice that when the maximal length of the widetilde is 'saturated', the two are correctly vertically stacked (see the double wide tilde over 'abcde').

*Note: I'm using `\DeclareRobustCommand` (instead of e.g. `\newcommand`) because I intend to use `\doublewidetilde` in section names.*

Answer (score 14):

Directly adapting my answer at [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode/101138#101138).  EDITED to use `\AC` from `wasysym` package, rather than `\sim` for the baseline tilde.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2014/03/10]
\usepackage{stackengine,wasysym}

\newcommand\dwidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{-.1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1\,\,$}{%
    \stackengine{\dimexpr-3.5\LMpt+.3pt}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\mkern.2mu\AC}{.5150\wd0}}{.7\ht0}%
    }{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\mkern.2mu\AC}{.5150\wd0}}{.7\ht0}%
    }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
\!\!}}

\def\test#1{$%
  \dwidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\dwidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\dwidetilde{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

\test{abcdefghijklm}
\test{abcdefghijk}
\test{abcdefghi}
\test{abcdefg}
\test{abcde}
\test{abc}
\test{ab}
\end{document}
```

[image]