# LaTeX superscripts problem with widetilde

Tags: superscripts, tilde

I tried to put a superscript (squared) with a `\xi` variable in the `\widetilde` :

```
$\widetilde{\xi}^2 = (\widetilde{\xi})^2 \neq \widetilde{\xi^2}$
```

gives
[image]

Which seems to be se same things, whereas it is absolutly not ! So, I'm looking for some way to put my squared in `\widetilde{\xi}^2` slightly higher than my `\widetilde`.

This problem doesn't occur with a "small variable" like an `x` :

```
$\widetilde{x}^2 = (\widetilde{x})^2 \neq \widetilde{^2}$
```

gives[image]

which places correctly and readably my squared without any doubt.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `\tilde{\xi}^{2}`

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for an output like the one provided by `\widetilde{\xi\mkern 0mu}^{2}`.  The issue, here, is a very low-level feature of TeX that is documented in _The TeXbook_, Appendix G, Rule 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all, this might indeed be the answer you are looking for.  The reciprocal placement of a math accent and of a superscript (and/or subscript) is subject, when the “accentee” consists of a single character, to an exceptional treatment which is detailed in Rule 12 of Appendix G of *The TeXbook* (p. 443), and that can be informally described as the super-/sub-script being “fastened” directly to the character being accented.  To inhibit application of this exception, it suffices to add, under the accent, “something” that takes up no space, for example `\mkern 0mu`.

Here is a MWE:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\newcommand*{\ShowLists}{%
%   \begingroup
%       \showboxbreadth = 1000
%       \showboxdepth = 10
%       \tracingonline = 1
%       \showlists
%   \endgroup
}



\begin{document}

Test:
\( \widetilde{\xi}^{2}+\widetilde{\xi\mkern 0mu}^{2}\ShowLists \).
\ShowLists
Other test:
\( \tilde{\xi}^{2}+\tilde{\xi\mkern 0mu}^{2}\ShowLists \).\ShowLists

\end{document}
```

And this is the output it produces:

[image: Output of the code]

If you uncomment the body of the definition of the `\ShowLists` command, some tracing information will be shown during compilation, that explains exactly what is going on.

---

## Addition

It turned out that the OP wasn’t quite satisfied with the above solution: the exponent gets raised too much.  Then we propose a completely different method, which puts the superscript at the same vertical position that an exponent affixed to a parenthesis would be placed at.  Note, however, that this causes the superscript to clash with the tilde, so a little amount of space needs to be added on its left.  Note also that the braces around `\mathstrut` are *not* superfluous!  (This is because `\mathstrut` does *not* produce an atom by itself, but “something else” that is not capable of carrying super-/sub-scripts.)

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.



\begin{document}

A completely different approach:
\( \widetilde{\xi}^{2} \neq \widetilde{\xi}{\mathstrut}^{\>2} \).

\end{document}
```

The output in this second case is:

[image: Output of the 2nd code sample]

Comment: Is it possible to slightly drop also the squared ? I was looking for the equivalent function `\mkern` but vertically. To put the upper point of '2' at the same level as the `\tilde` ?

Comment: @AnthonyT.: Please see edit.

Answer (score 3):

Your problems stem from the fact you want to use `\widetilde` instead of `\tilde`, which is more appropriate both over `\xi` and `x`.

```
$\tilde{\xi}^{2}$\qquad
$\tilde{\xi}^{\,2}$\qquad
$\widetilde{\xi}^{2}$\qquad
$\widetilde{\xi}^{\,2}$\qquad
$\widetilde{\xi}{\mathstrut}^{\,2}$

$\tilde{x}^{2}$\qquad
$\tilde{x}^{\,2}$\qquad
$\widetilde{x}^{2}$\qquad
$\widetilde{x}^{\,2}$\qquad
$\widetilde{x}{\mathstrut}^{2}$
```

(I added no preamble and no end because this runs the same in plain TeX as in LaTeX.)

[image]

There is no way to mistake `\tilde{\xi}^{2}` for “xi squared with tilde applied to it” rather than “xi tilde squared”. Perhaps this is the case where a thin space `\,` can be used (not for `x`).

As you will notice, the wide tilde extends a bit outside of its bounding box, but in any case the smaller variant for it is too wide for a single lowercase letter; perhaps it can be used for uppercase letters.

Keep it small.

Answer (score 1):

Here I offer a substitute macro `\reallywidetilde`, based on, but different from my answer at [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode/101138#101138).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine,wasysym}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1\mathstrut$}%
  \stackengine{.40\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\ACC}{.5150\wd0}}{.3\ht0}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}
\def\ACC{\ooalign{\AC\cr\kern.25\LMpt\AC}}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
widetilde

$\widetilde{\xi}^2 = (\widetilde{\xi})^2 \neq \widetilde{\xi^2}$

$\widetilde{x}^2 = (\widetilde{x})^2 \neq \widetilde{x^2}$

reallywidetilde

$\reallywidetilde{\xi}^2 = (\reallywidetilde{\xi})^2 \neq \reallywidetilde{\xi^2}$

$\reallywidetilde{x}^2 = (\reallywidetilde{x})^2 \neq \reallywidetilde{x^2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but when I tried, I had a problem with `scalerel.sty`
 ! Undefined control sequence.
 \\Isnextbyte ...elax \relax \relax \ifdefstrequal 
                                                   {\SR@Letter@A }{\SR@Letter...`

Comment: @AnthonyT. Without knowing more, I am going to guess that your `etoolbox.sty` is quite out of date.  My version is `2015/08/02 v2.2a`.  The macro `\ifdefstrequal` was introduced to that package with version 2.1 on 2011-01-03.

Comment: Yes ! It was exactly that's what was missing. Thanks.