# Accent in letters over a Letter

Tags: accents

I would like to write something of the sort. It's a form of an accent but I do not know how to write letters instead of just dots or a tilde.

Thank you[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) just to be clear, it's a `\tau` with `e-m` written on top of it?

Comment: yes actually its a \matcal{T} but \tau is the same

Comment: @Werner The other question seem to treat only the `\mathrel` case...

Comment: @yo': The *answers* there use `\mathrel`. The *question* is about "put[ting] text over symbols", and `\tau` is a symbol in my opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are three additional possibilities. They vary in (a) the symbol used to connect "e" and "m" -- a mathematical minus sign or a simple dash -- and (b) the size of the superscript material -- `\scriptsize` or `\tiny`. Not knowing what "`e-m`" stands for, I don't dare offer an opinion on which form is best.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\mathit{e-m}}{\mathcal{T}}$
$\overset{\textit{e-m}}{\mathcal{T}}$
$\overset{\textit{\tiny e-m}}{\mathcal{T}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! used $\overset{\textit{\tiny e-m}}{\mathcal{T}}$

Comment: @MarkPace - Glad my code is useful. Just out of idle curiosity: What does this composite symbol signify?

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{.5pt}{\tau}{\scriptscriptstyle e-m}
  {O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}$
or
$\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1pt}{\tau}{\scalebox{.5}{$\scriptscriptstyle e-m$}}
  {O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a definition like `\newcommand\overtext[2]{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1pt}{#1}%
  {\scalebox{.5}{$\scriptscriptstyle #2$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}`, a simple invocation of `$\overtext{\tau}{e-m}$` accomplishes the task.

If the overset is actually text over a long tilde...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel,wasysym}
\newcommand\overtext[2]{%
  \savestack\tmp{$\scriptscriptstyle \reallywidealttilde{#2}$}
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{.5pt}{#1}%
    {\scalebox{.5}{\tmp}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}
\newcommand\reallywidealttilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{.5pt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\AC}{.5150\wd0}}{.6\ht0}%
  }{U}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}
\begin{document}
$\overtext{L}{e-m}$ versus $\overtext{L}{x}$ versus $\overtext{L}{Ax^2 + Bx + C}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\reallywidealttilde` macro is based on my answer at [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode/101138#101138).

Comment: I think it is a L, with a tilde accent and e-m over the tilde, instead of a tau.

Comment: I vote for the tau. I didn't known stackengine package, does it work only in math mode or there is an equivalent for normal text? Thank you!

Comment: @CarLaTeX `stackengine` can operate in both math and text mode, or mixed mode, if one is careful.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I have provided your version, as well.  Note if you need alignment fields as part of a stack, the `tabstackengine` package provides a front end to `stackengine` to do so.

Comment: The version is @Astrinus's one, not mine, :)

Comment: @Astrinus - In the meantime, the OP has commented that it should be `\mathcal{T}`...

Comment: @Mico: my comment was posted half an hour before: if I could see half an hour in the future, I'll be a tycoon ;-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Congratulations on passing the 100K rep mark, by the way!

Answer (score 6):

I see it as L with a tilde, but it can easily be changed to tau.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\tauem{\widetilde{\rule{4pt}{0pt}L\rule{4pt}{0pt}}\raisebox{1.1em}{\kern-15pt\tiny\ensuremath{e-m}}}
\begin{document}
$A\tauem B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you what I used was this: \newcommand\tauem{{\rule{4pt}{0pt}\mathcal{T}\rule{4pt}{0pt}}\raisebox{1.1em}{\kern-15pt\tiny\ensuremath{e-m}}} $\tauem$

Answer (score 6):

This only works in normal style, but I'd avoid using such symbols in subscripts or superscripts anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\overtildewd}
\newlength{\overtildewdaux}
\newcommand{\overtilde}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth\overtildewd{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}%
  \settowidth\overtildewdaux{$\textstyle#2$}%
  \ifdim\overtildewdaux>\overtildewd\setlength{\overtildewd}{\overtildewdaux}\fi
  \overset{\scriptscriptstyle#1}{%
    \widetilde{\makebox[\overtildewd]{$\textstyle#2$}}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\[
\overtilde{e}{L}\qquad\overtilde{e-m}{L}
\]
\end{document}
```

This measures the text above the tilde and the base, getting the widest. Then `\widetilde` is applied to a box containing the base set centered in a box with the required width, and we apply `\overset` for setting the part above the tilde.

[image]

If the symbol is just a T (maybe calligraphic), there's not much more than `\overset`; you might just want to make the upper material smaller.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\overset{e-m}{\mathcal{T}}\qquad
\overset{\scriptscriptstyle e-m}{\mathcal{T}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: check the comments -- the base letter is supposed to be `\mathcal{T}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, interpreting that picture was difficult.