# Strike-through Tilde Accent

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, accents

I am working with graphs (*V*, *E*) which have a fixed number of common neighbours and common non-neighbours for each pair of adjacent vertices, and non-adjacent vertices as well. To denote these four invariants, I'm using the following symbols:

[image]

I'm not too keen on it though (I don't like how `_\sim` and `_\nsim` look). I'm considering using the `\tilde` accent, but I would like an analogous `\nottilde` accent, that is, a stricken-through `\tilde` accent:

[image]

I'd imagine creating such a command would involve quite a bit of hassle, especially to be compatible with `\widetilde`. I have no idea how to go about creating it (I used paint for the picture above).

I'm also open to other suggestions for this notation! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "compatible with `\widetilde`"?  How would you envision the proper way to strike through a `\widetilde`?  With the same small strike or with an enlarged one?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'd imagine the strikethrough to stretch out horizontally as the tilde does, however it's not that important to be honest. I'd be more interested in getting it to position itself correctly on the letter *f* or capital *A* for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\def\nottilde#1{\overset{\ifx#1f\hspace{.5ex}\fi\lower0.8ex\hbox{\tiny$\nsim$}}{#1}}
\def\xtilde#1{\overset{\ifx#1f\hspace{.5ex}\fi\lower0.8ex\hbox{\tiny$\sim$}}{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\tilde{e}\xtilde{e}\nottilde{e}\xtilde{f}\nottilde{f}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Is there any reason the `\sim` looks slimmer than the `\nsim` here?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to get `\xtilde{f}` and `\nottilde{f}` to look right also? I might use the letters *e* and *f*.

Answer (score 5):

A variation on my answer at [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode/101138#101138), showing `\reallywidetile` and `\reallywidenotilde`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine,wasysym}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\reallywideXtilde{#1}{\AC}}

\newcommand\reallywidenotilde[1]{\reallywideXtilde{#1}{\NAC}}

\newcommand\NAC{\stackengine{1.5\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle\AC$}{\smash{$\SavedStyle\vstretch{.35}{/}$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}

\newcommand\reallywideXtilde[2]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{-.1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{\kern.3ex%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu#2}{.5150\wd0}}{.6\ht0}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}


\def\test#1{$%
  \reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\qquad
  \textstyle\reallywidenotilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidenotilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidenotilde{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

\test{abcdefghijklm}
\test{abcdefghijk}
\test{abcdefghi}
\test{abcdefg}
\test{abcde}
\test{abc}
\test{ab}
\test{a}
\test{f}
\test{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]