# Big tilde over regular text, not in math mode?

Tags: tilde

I am looking for ways to put tilde over regular text. In math mode, we can put tilde above letters by `$\widetilde{ASK}$`. Is there a way to do the same thing for regular text longer than three letters? I mean: *not in math mode*, how to do big tilde over texts? The questions being answered all require math mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63545/5764) (you can set the text using `\mbox{...}`, even in math mode).

Comment: @Werner -- wouldn't `\text{...}` work too?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Of course, and requires [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Comment: I may not be clear enough. I mean how to do wide tilde above texts not in math mode.

Comment: @Werner Can you remove your duplication mark? The answer to the questions you provided all requires math mode. But I want to do big tilde WITHOUT MATH MODE.

Comment: @BrianDing: You can use `\newcommand{\bigtilde}[1]{\ensuremath{\widetilde{\mbox{#1}}}}` and then `Text \bigtilde{stuff} text` without worrying about math mode. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brute force method is to scale and position things. The primary advantage of brute force is that is is readily adjustable. Uses package `graphicx` for `\scalebox`. Note that this code DOES NOT REQUIRE MATH MODE, as requested.

```
This line of text sits above the tilde, and may clash without
using the raised strut, so you need to look closely at the result.\par
This line of text
\raisebox{0.5em}{\strut}\raisebox{0.2em}{\scalebox{3}{\char`\~}}\hspace{-1.3em}
has a big tilde.\par
```

Result:

[image: result of code]