# Defining `\subsetcong` and `\subsetsim` via proper tilde over and under `\subset`

Tags: macros, subscripts, superscripts, tilde, definition

I'd like to define a new command `\subsetcong` that would typeset a tilde over `\subseteq` to make it look similar to how tilde is over `=` in `\cong`. And also, I'd like to define `\subsetsim` to mean a `\subset` with a like tilde under, similar to `\subsetapprox`.

I am aware of this post: [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode), but the answer does not satisfy me, it feels needlessly complex. 'Detexify' app, didn't help much either, but I found one more symbol, which illustrates what I want with `\subsetsim`: `\lesssim`, only instead of `<` I need `\subset`.

The idea is to use `A \subsetcong B` or `A \subsetsim B` (yet to be decided), to mean something along the lines "there exists sub-element of B isomorphic (in a context-dependent sense) to A".

Any suggestions?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsetcong}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\subset@cong\relax}}
\newcommand{\subsetsim}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\subset@sim\relax}}

\newcommand{\subset@cong}[2]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil$#1##$\hfil\cr
      \sim\cr\subset\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\subset@sim}[2]{%
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil$#1##$\hfil\cr
      \subset\cr\noalign{\kern1pt}\sim\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\subsetcong B\subsetsim C$

$\scriptstyle A\subsetcong B\subsetsim C$

$\scriptscriptstyle A\subsetcong B\subsetsim C$

\end{document}
```

Some refinements as per your comment, adjust to suit.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsetcong}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\subset@cong\relax}}
\newcommand{\subsetsim}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\subset@sim\relax}}

\newcommand{\subset@cong}[2]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil##\cr
      \scalebox{0.9}{$#1\sim$}\cr
      \noalign{%
        \ifx#1\displaystyle\kern-0.5pt\else
        \ifx#1\textstyle\kern-0.5pt\fi\fi
      }%
      $#1\subset$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\subset@sim}[2]{%
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil##\cr
      $#1\subset$\cr\noalign{\kern0.5pt}\scalebox{0.9}{$#1\sim$}\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\subsetcong B\subsetsim C$

$\scriptstyle A\subsetcong B\subsetsim C$

$\scriptscriptstyle A\subsetcong B\subsetsim C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Precisely, beautiful answer @egreg, Thank You!

Also, I just found `\subsim` and `\supsim` in `stix` package, which resolves `\subsetsim` as well.

Comment: One small thing though, I've been playing around with your code in attempt to do two things: 1) make `\sim` closer to `\subset`, particularly in case of `\subsetcong` (in case of `\subsetsim` it's a matter of setting `\kern#pt`); 2) make `\sim` vertically align on the left side with `\subset`, i.e. to scale `\sim` down a bit. Would appreciate if you could address these two when time permits.

Comment: @PiotrTarasov Added.

Comment: perfecto and arigato my friend! @egreg