# How to write tilde symbol

Tags: math-mode, accents

I want to write big `$\tilde$` symbol above `$A[i]$`. If I try just like  `$\tilde{A[i]}$`, it does not work. How to do this?

Comment: Either `\widetilde`, or [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63545/5764) for something bigger/wider.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It has been solved by comment.

Comment: @Werner Please make your comment an answer.