# Spacing problem of really wide tilde

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, accents, tilde, scalerel

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255030/107173), I implement two versions of `\widetilde`, which is wide enough to cover all the text I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stackengine,scalerel}
\newlength\A
\ExplSyntaxOn
%first method, based on stackon
\newcommand{\wtildea}[1]{
    \settowidth{\A}{#1}
    \stackon[-7pt]{$#1$}{\hstretch{\fp_eval:n{\dim_to_fp:n{\A}/21}}{\widetilde{\phantom{#1}}}}
}

%second method, based on tikz
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}
\newcommand{\wtildeb}[1]{
    \settowidth{\A}{$#1$}
    \ooalign{$\tikz{\node[xscale=\fp_eval:n{\dim_to_fp:n{\A}}/5.5]{$\widetilde{\phantom{x}}$}}$\cr\hidewidth$#1$\hidewidth\cr}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$$xxAAAAAAAAAAAAxx$$
$$xx\wtildea{AAAAAAAAAAAA}xx$$
$$xx\wtildeb{AAAAAAAAAAAA}xx$$
\end{document}
```

However, they both have spacing issues, and the first solution causes the text with tilde shifts to right:
[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: The node needs `inner~sep=+0pt`.

Comment: That works, and I need to add some yshift. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TikZ solution needs `inner sep` of zero, this is a padding around the text that not only contributes to the width of the TikZ picture, it will also get scaled the same.

I've also added a `\vphantom{#1}` to it so that it gets the proper vertical dimensions. Using `baseline` and `anchor = base` makes sure the node is also placed correctly vertically.

As an option, I've added an alternative with `\resizebox` from the `graphics` package (loaded by `graphicx` which is loaded by `tikz`).

Both solutions won't work in subscripts or in superscripts.
A little bit more work is necessary.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\wtildea[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \settowidth{\dimen0}{$#1$}%
    \rlap{\resizebox{\dimen0}{\totalheight}{$\widetilde{\phantom{x\vphantom{#1}}}$}}%
  \endgroup
  #1}
\newcommand*{\wtildeb}[1]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \tikz[baseline]
      \node[anchor=base, inner sep=+0pt, xscale={width("$#1$")/width("$x$")}]
        {$\widetilde{\phantom{x\vphantom{#1}}}$};%
    \cr\hidewidth$#1$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\[xx         AAAAAAAAAAAA xx\]
\[xx\wtildea{AAAAAAAAAAAA}xx\]
\[xx\wtildeb{AAAAAAAAAAAA}xx\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why do you add an `x` in `\phantom{}`?

Comment: @YijunYuan It was in your original code as well. That's the base width for `\widetilde`, that's also the denominator for the `xscale` factor. (The `\resizebox` does these calculations internally.) If you put nothing in it you divide by 0 to get a scaling factor. You can, of course use something else or an explicit length instead. A `\widetilde{x}` covers the width of `x` perfectly while `xxx` or more leave a bit uncovered left and right which will get accentuated by the scaling.